# Athena/HiveQLのADD PARTITIONで型キャストはできない？

Tags: aws, sql

### 質問

以下のように型キャストをしようとすると `missing 'column' at 'partition'` というエラーが出るのは何故でしょうか。

```sql
ALTER TABLE nekketsuuu_athena_test
ADD
  PARTITION (dt=cast('2019-12-30' as date)) LOCATION 's3://ほにゃらら...'
;
```

### 経緯

Amazon Athena (HiveQL) において、次のようにして[パーティション分割](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/athena/latest/ug/partitions.html)が設定されたテーブルを作りました。

```sql
-- S3 に適当な実データを TSV として置いています。今回の問題の原因とは関係ないはずです。
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS nekketsuuu_athena_test (
    word1 string,
    word2 string,
    word3 string,
    word4 string,
    word5 string,
    word6 string
)
PARTITIONED BY (dt date)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
    'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
    'serialization.format' = '1',
    'input.regex' = 
'([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*)')
LOCATION
    's3://nekketsuuu-athena/'
;
```

ここで、パーティション用に指定した列 `dt` の型は `date` になっています。

続いてパーティションを `ADD` するため、string 型から date 型へ[キャスト](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-CastingDates)しつつ `dt` を指定するように書きました。

```sql
ALTER TABLE nekketsuuu_athena_test
ADD
  PARTITION (dt=cast('2019-12-30' as date)) LOCATION 's3://nekketsuuu-athena/2019/12/30'
-- ...(省略)...
;
```

しかしこれだと `line 3:3: missing 'column' at 'partition' (service: amazonathena; status code: 400; error code: invalidrequestexception; request id:ほにゃらら)` というエラーが出てしまいます。

替わりに `dt='2019-12-30'` と書くとエラー無しで想定通りに動きました。

```sql
ALTER TABLE nekketsuuu_athena_test
ADD
  PARTITION (dt='2019-12-30') LOCATION 's3://nekketsuuu-athena/2019/12/30'
;
```

また `dt=DATE '2019-12-30'` でも OK でした（上手くドキュメントを見つけられませんでしたが、[おそらく](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-TimestampstimestampTimestamps)これが `date` 型のリテラルの記法です）。

```sql
ALTER TABLE nekketsuuu_athena_test
ADD
  PARTITION (dt=DATE '2019-12-30') LOCATION 's3://nekketsuuu-athena/2019/12/30'
;
```

`dt` は `date` 型なのに、どうして型キャストだとエラーが出るのでしょうか。また、`string` から `date` への[暗黙の型変換はできない](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-AllowedImplicitConversions)のに、文字列リテラルのみでもエラーが出ないのはなぜでしょうか？